# Add post with custom field value to WP Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I have created a custom field for blog posts in WordPress. It's a simple radio button for either "yes" or "no". I am wondering if there is a way to add an array field to the WP REST API that will contain all of those posts that have "yes" selected. I can provide more info if necessary. I haven't been able to find resources that really address this question specifically, but would appreciate any input or resources someone might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into the `functions.php` file:

```
function endpoint_acf() {
    $args = array(
      'meta_key'   => 'custom-fied-name', 
      'meta_value' => 'custom-field-value'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $the_query;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'endpoint-name', array(
        'methods' => array('GET', 'POST'),
        'callback'    => function() {
                return endpoint_acf();      
            },
    ));
});
```